# Continuous/Onto Function Between Topological Spaces

Tags: general-topology

Let $(U,T)$ and $(V,D)$ be topological spaces, where $D$ is the discrete topology.

Suppose that $f:U\to V$ be a function that is $T - D$ continuous.

If $f$ is surjective and D is the discrete topology on $V$, then $T$ is the discrete topology on $U$.

I do not believe that this is true and I am having a hard time developing a clear counterexample.

My initial thought is to use $f:R \to R$ and make $T$ be the usual topology since that is what I am most comfortable with.  I am getting confused on identifying a function that will be $T \to D$ continuous and surjective.

Any guidance will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are correct: it need not be true. Let $\mathscr{T}$ be the indiscrete topology on $\{0,1\}$, and let $\mathscr{D}$ be the discrete (and only!) topology on $\{0\}$. Let $f(0)=f(1)=0$. Then $f$ is continuous and surjective, but $\mathscr{T}$ is not the discrete topology on $\{0,1\}$.

For a less trivial example, let $\mathscr{T}$ be the [Sorgenfrey (or lower-limit) topology](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lower_limit_topology) on $\Bbb R$, let $\mathscr{D}$ be the discrete topology on $\Bbb Z$, and let

$$f:\mathscr{R}\to\mathscr{Z}:x\mapsto\lfloor x\rfloor\;,$$

where $\lfloor x\rfloor$ is the largest integer less than or equal to $x$. Then $f^{-1}[\{n\}]=[n,n+1)$ for each $n\in\Bbb Z$, and $[n,n+1)$ is open in the Sorgenfrey topology, so $f$ is continuous. Clearly $f$ is surjective, and $\mathscr{T}$ is not the discrete topology.

Comment: Would it still be false if you change f from surjective to injective?

Comment: @NUG: No, then it would be true. For each $u\in U$ you’d have $\{f(u)\}$ open in $V$, so continuity of $f$ would require $f^{-1}[\{f(u)\}]$ to be open; but if $f$ is injective, this inverse image is just $\{u\}$. Thus, each point of $U$ would have to be isolated, and $\mathscr{T}$ would be discrete.

Comment: I really appreciate your explanation, it is absolutely brings some clarity to it for me.  The only part I'm getting stuck on is the last sentence when you say isolated.  Can you elaborate on exactly what that means?

Comment: @NUG: A point $p$ in a topological space $X$ is an *isolated point* of $X$ if $\{p\}$ is an open set in $X$. Thus, $X$ has the discrete topology if and only if every point of $X$ is an isolated point.